# Input doesn't render in view

Tags: php, fat-free-framework, fuelux

I use fat free framework and fuelux repeater. When I create an html element in **controller** files, I can't see the element in **view**. I realize what the problem it is, but I don't know the solution.

[image: Checkbox in repeater]

Comment: Please tell us what you think the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print the raw HTML, since F3's template engine is automatically escaping it. Have a look at: https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/views-and-templates#DataSanitation

Either use `$f3->set('ESCAPE',FALSE);` to disable escaping globally (not recommended) or add a filter in your template for the variable you want to keep unescaped like this: `{{ @html_content | raw }}`